# Bound Field anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview

I want to put value from db to anchor tag in Bound field of GridView
Here is my code.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="u_id" ControlStyle-CssClass="bg-darkGreen"     
    HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="u_id" 
    HtmlEncode="false" 
    DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='Details.aspx?u_id={0}'>
    u_id</a>" >
```

But it is not showing value from db , it just showing U_id throughout the column.Is there any logic exists which take value from DataField and put in anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `HyperLinkField` as below

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="u_id" HeaderText="ID" 
     DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Details.aspx?u_id={0}" DataTextField="u_id" />
```